# Update two (individual operation/total operation) progressbars in GUI using BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Ok, I've been banging my head against this all day. I'm still fairly new to programming, and its quite possible that my entire approach here is misguided. But anyway...so I have a simple gui app with a listbox full of folders, and I'm executing an operation on every file in each folder sequentially. This is a very long operation, so I have two progress bars - one for each file, and one for each folder.

```
private void buttonApplySelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     double percentToIncrement = 100.0 / Convert.ToDouble(selectedDirList.Count);
     double percentComplete = percentToIncrement;
     folderProgressBar.Value = 0;
     foreach (string dir in selectedDirList)
     {
             engine = new OEngine.OEngine(dir, backgroundWorker1);
             engine.ProcessSelected(processType);

             int percentCompleteInt = Convert.ToInt32(percentComplete);
             folderProgressBar.Value = percentCompleteInt;
             percentComplete += percentToIncrement;
     }         
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
     fileProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

The BackgroundWorker itself is passed down to the engine, and it updates its progress within the code of the engine processing that folder. (This is probably my first mistake.) The UI catches that ProgressChanged event and updates the fileProgressBar in it's own thread.

But the folderProgressBar needs to be updated once every pass through the for loop, but it gives me `Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'folderProgressBar' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

If I move it out of the for loop, it wont update after each folder.
If I move all the UI updating out of the DoWork function, and call the DoWork function in a for loop instead, it obviously doesnt wait for each folder to finish and I get "the worker is still busy" exception.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

The general solution for windows form:
Use

```
WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext syncContext = new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext();
```

...

```
//in the background work or any non UI Thread

//Trigger an update in the GUI thread; one can also use syncContext.Send (depending on the need for syncrhonous or async operation)
syncContext.Post(UpdateGUI, userData);

...

void UpdateGUI(object userData)
{
  //update your progress bar 
}
```

> ```
> If using wpf, declare a variable syncContex.
> ```

```
SynchronizationContext syncContext;
//And when in the UI thread, set the variable's value as
syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

//Then from the non-UI thread, 
syncContext.Post(UpdateGUI, userData);
```

Comment: I'm not entirely following where each block of code goes.